# Android AVD App not installing

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have a question regarding android AVD. At the moment I have an application that is compatible from SDK 8 to 19. I created a simple test project and tried to run it on Android AVD using API 18 (or any other lower API) and the project works perfectly on it. However when I use my application, it sometimes gives me a red X or a sign of exclamation and won't install the application on to the emulator.

Any ideas? any help would be very appreciated on this matter. Thank you!

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse? 
Can you be more specific about that "sometimes"? Is it like: From time to time, I can't install my app but when I try again, it works. Or is it more like: After some time, I can't install my app and I have to uninstall it from emulator/delete the emulator and create new one to make it work again?

Comment: Eclipse newest kepler.

Comment: Ok, well, it sometimes happen that the emulator stops responding and needs to be restarted. Maybe this is your case. Or, try another thing: Next time you get the error, open TaskManager, look for process called adb and kill it. This will restart the "connection" between eclipse and emulator.

Comment: I will try to kill adb server and see if that helps. I have already closed emulator and restarted it several times with no effect.